# XSPF Playlist Player not loading image

Tags: php, wordpress, flash, xspf

I am using a [XSPF Player](http://www.xspf-player.com/) for my [website](http://www.markjoeylavapie.com/akasa/music/) its working well, but the only problem is, the Image is not loading by default, I need to play one track to display image. 
Here's my code.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="540" height="170" data="http://www.markjoeylavapie.com/akasa/wp-content/themes/akasa/music/xspf_player.swf?playlist_url=http://www.markjoeylavapie.com/akasa/wp-content/themes/akasa/music/portal-playlist.xspf&autoload=1">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.markjoeylavapie.com/akasa/wp-content/themes/akasa/music/xspf_player.swf?playlist_url=http://www.markjoeylavapie.com/akasa/wp-content/themes/akasa/music/portal-playlist.xspf&autoload=1" />
<param name="allownetworking" value="internal" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="never" />
<param name="enableJSURL" value="false" />
<param name="enableHREF" value="false" />
<param name="saveEmbedTags" value="true" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
```

Comment: It is working correctly, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YCtk5/).

Comment: yeah it is now, I just updated the flash file because I was using the previous version. Thanks anyway.